# Django: Get data from form and use it in queryset

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to take data from a django form and use it in a queryset? If so, how would I do it? Here's an example of how I would want it to work:

Form Example:

```
First Name: (User Enters First Name Here)
Last Name: (User Enters Last Name Here)
```

that data would then be used in a queryset like so:

```
ModelName.objects.filter(first_name=(First Name User Provided in Form), last_name=(Last Name Provided in form))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access data in `views.py` via `request.POST` and, from there, call any ORM methods. A simple example using Django's auth:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def search(request):
    users = \ 
        User.objects.filter(first_name=request.POST['firstname'],
                            last_name=request.POST['lastname'])
    if users:
        return HttpResponse(users[0].username)
    else:
        return HttpResponse('No match')
```